# A lot of CSS classes on element vs one specific class?

Tags: html, css, performance, stylesheet

I'm curious to know which way is 'best' performance wise, think of this simple general example, I wish to have an element which contains text, to be bold underlined and blue of colour.

I can use this way:

```
<p class="bold underlined blue">Happy little clouds</p>
```

or

```
<p class="bold-underlined-blue">Happy little trees</p>
```

The first would obviously produce more classes, but the ultimate re-use of these classes seems to be better than making the one very specific class, but again on the other hand, producing more classes, I presume this would have performance implications.

Comment: You'll be defining `font-weight: bold;` in plenty more other rules if you won't go for reusability. So "performance implications" shouldn't be a big deal on your first solution.

Comment: Performance-wise, in *your specific example*, the second one is better; the smaller the CSS file, the quicker it will load. But let's be real here - What is the actual use-case for specific classes on *every element* as opposed to re-usable? If you make a specific class for each element, you will always have *at least* as many CSS rules as elements on the page. If you go for re-usable classes, you could have 100 elements and only 10 rules. So in 99.9% of cases, *reusable classes* are the better way to go. Voting to close as "Primarily Opinion Based".

Comment: "Primarily Opinion Based" one way will render the quicker than the other and that is the question I was asking, but then there is usability vs readability which I agree is opinion based, not the question I was asking

Comment: There is no reliable, always-true answer, as neither is inherently best, it's situation-dependent. The bottom line is this: **The smaller the CSS file, the better performance your page will have.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former approach (using multiple classes) is definitely better. Not only can you style the elements **individually** with:

```
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.underlined {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

But you can also style them for specific combination with **each other** such as:

```
.bold.underlined.blue {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

In the above example, the `font-size` will only be applied if the corresponding element has all three classes, which would essentially be the same as the latter method in itself :)

Not only does using specialised classes give you more versatility, but it is also faster -- as you are likely to reuse styles like `font-weight: bold` multiple times throughout your document, a dedicated class means that you will only have to write the declaration once, rather than having to write it in each individual selector.

However, these specialised classes should only be created for things that you will reuse multiple times -- creating a specialised class for something that is only used once would be redundant.

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP is mainly concerned about performance issues. Try to address that as well along with your answer.